# VBScript - Bring Microsoft Edge window to foreground

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

My script launches a MS Edge window and then tries to log into Netflix with my credentials. The problem is, at times, the browser window comes up behind the CMD console and the script doesn't work.

How do I launch the browser in the foreground or bring it to the foreground after it's launched?

```
<!-- :
rem @Echo Off
Set "usr_name=#####"
Set "usr_pass=#####"

%SystemRoot%\System32\cscript.exe //NoLogo "%~f0?.wsf" "%browser%" "%usr_name%" "%usr_pass%"
Exit /B
-->
<Job>
  <Script Language="VBScript">
    Dim ObjShell, MyChrome
    Set ObjShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    MyChrome = Chr(34) & WScript.Arguments(0) & Chr(34)
    ObjShell.Run MyChrome & "--app=""https://www.netflix.com/login""", 1
    WScript.Sleep 5000
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    ObjShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(1))
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    ObjShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(2))
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 6000
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    ObjShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    WScript.Sleep 6000
    ObjShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
  </Script>
</Job>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to to use a powershell cmdlet to minimize all windows before running the script that launches the browser.

'''powershell -command "(new-object -com shell.application).minimizeall()'''

Answer (score 1):

Scripts that depend on `SendKeys` are notoriously unreliable. A more reliable approach is to control the browser with [Seleniumbasic](https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/) and [Chrome driver](https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/) or use [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) in a C# program. Barring that, one option for adding window control functionality to your existing script is to use the command line tool [Cmdow](https://ritchielawrence.github.io/cmdow/). For example:

`ObjShell.Run "cmdow ""Netflix*"" /MAX",1,False`

Update:

You can also try the built-in `AppActivate` method:

`ObjShell.AppActivate "Netflix"`

Comment: @LesFrench I need a solution that's preferably compatible with Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Also, I'd rather not install any external tools to do this. Is there no way to bring a window to the foreground with VBScript?

Comment: Yes, try `ObjShell.AppActivate "Netflix"`

Comment: ObjShell.AppActivate "Netflix" doesn't work. I used a powershell cmdlet to minimize all windows before I run this script. This way the browser window comes up as the active window all the time.

Comment: The `AppActivate` did work on my computer with Netflix in a Chrome tab, but it's a YMMV thing. Minimizing all at start sounds like a better approach.